# Почему выдает в конце вывода массива undefined?

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции

Функция выводит массив в обратном порядке. Почему в конце вывода добавляется undefined?

```js
function reverseLog (array) {
   var index = array.length;
   while(index-- > 0) {
    console.log(array[index]);
   }
}

var someArray = [7, 12, 4, 8, 45, 3, 1];
console.log(reverseLog(someArray));
```

Comment: Потому что второй консоль.лог выводит значение, которая вернула функция реверсЛог. А функция реверсЛог ничего не вернула...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разберу ответ `Igor`
Если выполнить этот код, выводится undefined

```js
function reverseLog(array) {
}

var someArray = [7, 12, 4, 8, 45, 3, 1];
console.log(reverseLog(someArray));
```

Это потому, что функция reverseLog ничего не возвращает.
Для примера сделаем так, что функция всегда будет возвращать 1:

```js
function reverseLog(array) {
  return 1;
}

var someArray = [7, 12, 4, 8, 45, 3, 1];
console.log(reverseLog(someArray));
```

Теперь выводится 1, а не undefined
А ваш код что делал -> функция ничего не возвращала (поэтому получался undefined), а внутри себя делала console.log

Можно в этой функции написать `return значение` и тогда функция `` вернёт нужное значение после того, как выполнится

```js
function reverseLog (array) {
   var index = array.length;
   while(index-- > 0) {
    console.log(array[index]);
   }
   return 'Что-то вернулось';
}

var someArray = [7, 12, 4, 8, 45, 3, 1];
console.log(reverseLog(someArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function reverseLog (array) {
   var index = array.length;
   while(index-- > 0) {
    console.log(array[index]);
   }
}

var someArray = [7, 12, 4, 8, 45, 3, 1];
reverseLog(someArray);
```